# Can someone explain how to work with navigation drawer in android?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

Can someone explain how to add new views to the navigation drawer in android? I began a new project with the 'Navigation drawer' layout and it spawned a project with a 'NavigationDrawerFragment' class. I'm trying to get a better understanding of the method's functions and how it works with the xml so that I know how to create and navigate through views. Essentially I want to create 12 subviews under one top view and other low level views added to other 3 top views. Where each top view would have it's own layout and function.

Comment: It is explained in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29 and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionEvents for starters.

Comment: Did you read any documentation yet?  Tried searching on here or Google?

Comment: This is **not** a tutorial site.

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Every time a menu item is clicked this method is being called. You should return true if you consume the event. Use `menuItem.getItemId()` to check which menu item was clicked.

> This hook is called whenever an item in your options menu is selected.
>   The default implementation simply returns false to have the normal
>   processing happen (calling the item's Runnable or sending a message to
>   its Handler as appropriate). You can use this method for any items for
>   which you would like to do processing without those other facilities.
>
> Derived classes should call through to the base class for it to
>   perform the default menu handling.
>
> Parameters
>   item The menu item that was selected. Returns boolean
>   Return false to allow normal menu processing to proceed, true to
>   consume it here.